# navigation controller doesn't work

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Signup `UIViewController` design that validates email, password and confirm password.

`Signup` is embedded in `NavigationController`

```
func showAlert(ttl:String,msg:String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "\(ttl)", message: "\(msg)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (email.text != nil && password.text != nil && confrimPassword.text != nil){
        if !(isValidEmail(testStr: email.text!)){
        showAlert(ttl: "Invaild Email-ID", msg: "Please enter an valid Email-ID")
    }
        else if !(isValidPassword(testStr: password.text)){
        showAlert(ttl: "Invalid Password", msg: "Password must have at least one uppercase,one digit,one lowercase and minimum 8 characters")
    }
        else if !(passwordMatch(password: password.text!, confirmPassword: confrimPassword.text!)){
        showAlert(ttl: "Passwords doesn't Match", msg: "Please re-enter your password")
    }
    else{
        if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet {
            Authentication.Signup(for: email.text!, password: password.text!,finished: { resdata in do{ let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: resdata) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                print(res)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let view: Verification = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Verify") as! Verification
                    view.email = self.email.text! 
     //doesnot work
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
                }

            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            showAlert(ttl: "No Internet", msg: "Please check your internet connection")
        }
    }
    }
    else{
       self.showAlert(ttl: "Enter all Credentials", msg: " ")
        }
    }

}
```

Tried using segue also that doesn't suit my requirements

Comment: No need of `DispatchQueue.main.async {`

Comment: have you chacked your block is executing or its going in error block

Comment: Yes, put a print inside the "catch" to see if your do->catch block gets an error, if it does, then the problem is not in your navigationController, but the way you parse your JSON, or the way you cast it into Dictionary. Post also the JSON you get, maybe it is not [String : Any] but an Array of dictionaries? Also, make sure your viewController is embeded into a navigationController. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
Authentication.Signup(for: email.text!, password: password.text!,finished: { resdata in do{
let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: resdata) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
print(res)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Verify") as! Verification
    controller.email = self.email.text!
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```